# an equation with finitely many solutions in positive integers

Tags: calculus, limits, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Prove that the equation $x^8 = n! + 1$ has finitely many solutions where $x$ and $n$ are positive integers.

Assume for a contradiction that there are infinitely many solutions $(x,n), x,n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}.$ Write $n! = (x^4 + 1)(x^2 +1)(x^2-1).$ If $p$ is a $3\mod 4$ prime dividing $n!,$ it must divide $x^2-1$ as the other factors are of the form $a^2+1.$ Indeed, assume $p$ is prime, and $p | a^2 + 1.$ If $a$ is a multiple of $p$, $p \not | a^2 + 1,$  so assume $p\not | a.$ Then by Fermat's little theorem, $1\equiv a^{p-1} \equiv (a^2)^{(p-1)/2} \equiv (-1)^{(p-1)/2} $ so $(p-1)/2 $ is even and $p\equiv 1\mod 4.$

For convenience, assume $p$ is prime whenever mentioned below. Thus $\prod_{p\leq n, p\equiv 3\mod 4}p^{v_p(n!)} | x^2 - 1\Rightarrow \prod_{p\leq n, p\equiv 3\mod 4}p^{v_p(n!)}\leq x^2 -1\leq \sqrt[4]{n!+1}$ for $x\ge 1$ (as $x^8 = n!+1$ by assumption and $(x^2-1)^4 \leq x^8$ for $x\ge 1$). We also have for $p\leq n/2$ and $n > 2$ that $ \frac{2}3\frac{n}p < \lfloor \frac{n}p\rfloor$. Also, by Legendre's theorem, $v_p(n!) \ge \lfloor \frac{n}p\rfloor$. Thus for $n > 2, \prod_{p\leq n/2, p \equiv 3\mod 4 } p^{\lfloor n/p\rfloor}\leq \prod_{p\leq n, p\equiv 3\mod 4}p^{v_p(n!)}  \leq \sqrt[4]{n!+1}\leq \sqrt[4]{n^n}$ for $\Rightarrow \frac{2}3n \sum_{p\leq n/2, p\equiv 3\mod 4} \frac{\log p}p < \sum_{p\leq n/2, p\equiv 3\mod 4} \lfloor\frac{n}p\rfloor\log p \leq \frac{n\log n}4.$ Dividing by $\frac{2}3 n$ yields $ \sum_{p\leq n/2, p\equiv 3\mod 4} \frac{\log p}p \leq \frac{3\log n}8\Rightarrow \sum_{p\leq n, p\equiv 3\mod 4} \leq \frac{3\log n}8 + C$ for some constant $C$, which would be a contradiction if one could show that $ \sum_{p\leq n, p\equiv 3\mod 4} = \frac{\log n}2 + O(1).$

> Is there a simpler approach that doesn't involve using the final result?

Comment: See also [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39210/solve-in-positive-integers-n-mm1) for references. Here $n!=P(m)=m^8-1$.